# Time span parsing failing on leading year

Tags: java, regex

I use following regex to to parse text and find the first time or timespan within:

> (([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(| )(-|bis)(|
>   ))?([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])((:|\.)|Uhr| Uhr)

If I have a text containing "`18:00 - 19:00`" ist will find two matches for start and end time.

But it will fail in the following case:

> 28.11.2018 - 19:00

The first and only time in this text is `19:00`, but the regex "sees" `18 - 19:00` in the text and falsely interprets the year as first part of a time span.

How would you modify the regex, so that the year is ignored?

**Here some more context:**

I have an event calendar with a lot of entries like that:

> a) "Party at Shooters with DJ Max, today at 11:00 pm. Don´t miss out!"
>
> b) "Opening day for exhibition "Bourgeois", today 6:00 pm - 8:00 pm at
>   gallery Alpha."

To auto generate a daily timetable of all events, the first occurence of a time or timespan within the text is needed.

So this is...

> for a) 11:00 pm
>   for b) 6:00 pm - 8:00 pm

As this event calendar is in Germany we write the time format localized in the following way.

For 11:00 pm we ca write...

> "23:00" or "23 Uhr" or "23:00 Uhr"

And a timespan can be expressed the following way in Gemany:

> "18-20 Uhr" or "18:00 - 19:00" or 18 bis 19 Uhr" and so on....

However, in case a) of a single time there will be one match for the regex and in case of a timespan, there will be two matches (start and end time). If the time matches, it is very easy to extract the hour and the minute.

So far, the regex works perfect for nearly all cases and extracts times and timestamps. But in one case the regex fails:

If you have e.g. a date "18:00" (= 6pm) this time is found.

But sometimes the date is preceeded by a date, you have something like "11.12.2018 - 19:00" (meaning 6pm at 2018/12/11). The matcher will see the "18" of the year as start time and 19:00 as end time. So it´s misinterpreted as "18-19:00" (6-7pm) instead of just 19:00 (7pm).

What I want ist a modification of the regex ignoring the "18" of the year 2018.

Comment: I read twice and still don't understand your post, can you clarify ? of what does work, what should be matched and what does not work ?

Comment: Hi @azro, I just added some more info. Thanks for your feedback!